# Connect R with MySQL

Tags: r

I am getting error while connecting R with MySQL.
code:

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'xxxxx', password = 'xxxxxx', 
dbname = 'database_name', host = 'localhost')
```

> error: Error in .local(drv, ...) :    Failed to connect to database:
>   Error: Access denied for user 'nikhil_read'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Can anyone help me out on this error to fix it out?

Comment: It's just an authentication error. Either you're not using the correct password or you've enabled some different type of authentication such as key pair.

Comment: I strongly advice you to **NOT** share sensitive information like `user` and `password`. We do not care about your credentials anyway. Problem can be solved without us knowing them